# How save PrivateKey from certificate in Cordova plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to save and than use PrivateKey from cordova plugin to another cordova plugin. My questions is, how to save this key and use it in another cordova plugin or send this key in callback or save this key to PEM file.

This is Java code of Cordova plugin

```
public class CertificatePlugin extends CordovaPlugin implements KeyChainAliasCallback {
  private static String[] KEYTYPES = {"PKCS12"};
  CallbackContext callbackContext = null;
  @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext
                      callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    if ("selectCert".equals(action)) {
        return selectCertificate();

    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean selectCertificate() {
    Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
    KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(activity, this, KEYTYPES, null,
                                   null, -1, null);

    return true;
  }


  private PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {

    try {
        PrivateKey pk = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), alias);
        return pk;
    } catch (KeyChainException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }

  @Override
  public void alias(String alias) {
    callbackContext.success(alias);
    PrivateKey key = getPrivateKey (alias);   
 }
```

}

Comment: Your title is meaningless. Certificates don't contain private keys.